# Primary Key null error in @NamedStoredProcedureQuery for eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am getting following error while calling oracle stored procedure

Exception Description: The primary key read from the row [DatabaseRecord(
        retval => null
        error_message => null)] during the execution of the query was detected to be null.  Primary
keys must not contain null.
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="CCM_ASSIGN_LOOP" referenceClass=CcmAssignLoop )

My Entity is

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name="CCM_ASSIGN_LOOP", procedureName="TCS.CCM_ASSIGN_LOOP",         resultClass=CcmAssignLoop.class,  
parameters={  
    @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="psubno",name="psubno",direction=Direction.IN),  
    @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="upd_user",name="upd_user",direction=Direction.IN),  
    @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="ccloop_in",name="ccloop_in",direction=Direction.IN),
    @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="ccstage_in",name="ccstage_in",direction=Direction.IN),
    @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="retval",name="retval",direction=Direction.OUT),
    @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="error_message",name="error_message",direction=Direction.OUT)
 }  
)

public class CcmAssignLoop implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public CcmAssignLoop() {
    super();
}

@Id
private String  psubno;
private String  upd_user;
private String  ccloop_in;
private BigDecimal  ccstage_in;
private String  retval;
private String  error_message;

public String getPsubno() {
    return psubno;
}
public void setPsubno(String psubno) {
    this.psubno = psubno;
}
public String getUpd_user() {
    return upd_user;
}
public void setUpd_user(String upd_user) {
    this.upd_user = upd_user;
}
public String getCcloop_in() {
    return ccloop_in;
}
public void setCcloop_in(String ccloop_in) {
    this.ccloop_in = ccloop_in;
}
public BigDecimal getCcstage_in() {
    return ccstage_in;
}
public void setCcstage_in(BigDecimal ccstage_in) {
    this.ccstage_in = ccstage_in;
}
public String getRetval() {
    return retval;
}
public void setRetval(String retval) {
    this.retval = retval;
}
public String getError_message() {
    return error_message;
}
public void setError_message(String error_message) {
    this.error_message = error_message;
}

}
```

Below is code for calling stored procedure

```
Query q = tabsEm.createNamedQuery("CCM_ASSIGN_LOOP");
        q.setParameter("psubno", subno);
        q.setParameter("upd_user", "abc");
        q.setParameter("ccloop_in", "xyz");
        q.setParameter("ccstage_in", new BigDecimal(5));

      //  CcmAssignLoop ccmAssignLoop   =   (CcmAssignLoop)q.getSingleResult();

        q.getResultList();
```

Above mentioned column are not a primary key, whu i am getting this error.

Update:

My procedure on oracle start like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TCS.CCM_ASSIGN_LOOP(PSUBNO IN VARCHAR2, UPD_USER IN VARCHAR2, CCLOOP_IN IN VARCHAR2, CCSTAGE_IN IN NUMBER, RETVAL OUT VARCHAR2, ERROR_MESSAGE OUT VARCHAR2)
     IS
OLD_CCSTAGE     CCM_USER_INFO.CCLOOP_STAGE%TYPE;
OLD_CCLOOP      CCM_USER_INFO.CCLOOP%TYPE;
PROC_CONTRNO    CRM_USER_INFO.CONTRNO%TYPE;
TEMP_COUNT      NUMBER;
RET_VAL         VARCHAR2(100);
V_ERROR_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(256);
```

i can see RETVAL and RET_VAL, could thiss error due to this?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

It may be a case sensitivity issue. Try making the `queryParameter` attribute values all uppercase, e.g.:

```
@StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="PSUBNO",name="psubno",direction=Direction.IN),
```

I'm thinking that because database column names (as well as stored procedure parameters) are uppercase by default if you don't specify the name using the `Column` annotation.

Comment: I did changes according to your suggetions but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting "resultClass=CcmAssignLoop.class", this means the procedure will return the data to build instances of this class, your procedure does not, so do not set this.  Then you will just get the raw data back.